# Where to put forms / alternative views in a RESTful html app?

Tags: html, forms, rest

Let's assume an web application that for each URI presents a nice html view for GET requests and allows to update the underlying resource through POST/PUT/PATCH/WHATEVER.

How do I then expose various forms that actually allow performing such requests from the browser? And broader: assuming I have alternative views (possibly also HTML) for the same resource, where do I put those? Arguably, such forms can be considered alternative views, so having an answer to the broader question would be ideal.

---

*Edit:* To clarify, my question is not about pure data APIs serving JSON or whatnot, but about HTML apps such as Stackoverflow. For example you can get the collection of questions under [`/questions`](/questions) and this particular one at [`/questions/24696982`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696982/) which makes sense. To get the form to add a new question, you will have to use [`/questions/ask`](/questions/ask), which I'm not sure is alright. And that form POSTs to [`/questions/ask/submit`](/questions/ask/submit), which seems just plain wrong. Making a GET request to that URL yields a 404 (if anything it should be a 405). The form should be POSTing to `/questions`. Still I would like to know whether at least the URI for the form is considered acceptable in a RESTful system.

Comment: I can understood your question what u want ?

Comment: Don't get your question either. But http://haltalk.herokuapp.com/ and http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/console/ might interest you.

Comment: How is this too broad?

Answer (score 5):

You have a website like, the one way to build a real RESTFull API is to split the frontend and the API - thats in my opinion the best way (some may disagree) - maybe some other don't think like this but lets say the frontend team got `www.domain` and your team for the API got `api.domain`.

```
GET api.domain/questions - Retrieves a list of tickets   
GET api.domain/questions/12 - Retrieves a specific ticket   
POST api.domain/questions - Creates a new ticket  
PUT api.domain/questions/12 - Updates ticket #12  
DELETE api.domain/questions/12 - Deletes ticket #12  
PATCH api.domain/questions/12 - Partially updates ticket #12 #I only want to display that this also exists - i don't really use it...
```

**AWESOME EDIT: As you can see also stackoverflow uses this method: api.stackexchange.com**

So as you can see you can have these structure - but you also can have a form on `www.domain/questions/ask` and this form would send the request to `api.domain/questions` via `POST`. I want to refer to: https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1221/designing_a_beautiful_rest_json_api_video its a really nice podcast you should have heard.

### **EDIT: (another point of view)**

Another idea is that you can simply choose which content should come back (Json,XML,HTML) if your client sends you the right Accept-Header.

Example 1:

```
       URL           REQUEST       ACCEPT HEADER               RESPONSE                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
domain/questions      GET        application/json   all questions as json
domain/questions      GET        text/html          the page as html with all questions
domain/questions/ask  GET        text/html          Your html for to add a new question
domain/questions      POST       application/json   Add a new new questions (this would be called from ./ask to add the new questions
domain/questions/ask  GET        application/json   404 Status-Code because on questions/ask you don't have implemented any resource
```

Example-2:

```
       URL              REQUEST     ACCEPT HEADER               RESPONSE                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
domain/questions/12       GET      application/json   Shows the questions with the ID 12 as JSON
domain/questions/12       GET      text/html          Shows the HTML representation of your page
domain/questions/12/edit  GET      text/html          Your html for to edit a the question
domain/questions/12       PUT      application/json   Updates the questions with the ID 12 // just to add the PATCH thing.. i don't really use it but if you don't update the whole object you could/should use PATCH instead of PUT :p
domain/questions/12/edit  GET      application/json   404 Status-Code because on questions/ask you don't have implemented any resource
```

Yesterday I told you about the first idea (which is - I think for using an api as a team (one for frontend and one team that develops the api - a better way) but as @jackweirdy commented (thanks for that - i then searched a lot and was looking at other podcasts from developer around the world and how they would do that) below it's really all up to you - it's your api and at the end you/your team will decide for one way. Hope this helps you or other that looking for how to build a API on a REST background.

The examples in the EDIT-Section would be (if I got it right) not like here on stackoverflow

Comment: I disagree, I think it works best when they're on the same domain (though I might concede a separate url root). That way authentication works with any cookie-stored credentials you may get in your browser.

Comment: I think its a big opinion based desicion. If you work in teams One for Frontend and one for the api. But thanks for you reply - thanks :)

Comment: That's true; and I guess it depends what you're building and whether you're starting from scratch or retroactively adding the API to it :)

Comment: You are right. ;) at the end always the team who has developed the applications knows how and why they are doing things like they have done it. :)

Comment: @jackweirdy maybe my edit will make you agree with me :) I searched a lot and - yes - I found some other opinions/design-decisions and the second one would be (for me) a possible way to do an api like the asker of this questions maybe want it to have.

Comment: @jackweirdy found this little gem: api.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: I'm really not interested in APIs as I find that quite evident. As for forms, I don't see how your answer differs from that of jackweirdy.

Comment: You Asked a questions on how it would be a good way to use forms or where to Place a form. REST isn't something you do on Frontend neither it is a Way How to structure your homepage URL! Its a pattern/way to Design a API - so if you are interessted into REST you should ne interessted on how to Design a API because that is the background NOT your way on structure the URL in the Frontend! ;)

Comment: As you can see in the First Part - i showed you what REST is - and as you can see it is about designing a API not designing a pattern for writing a url for an enduser! ;) and so there are major differences between these two answers! Also i showed you how stack overflow handles this - and they also handle this problem with the first point and this point jackweirdy doesn't show in his answer! so I hope you see the difference - maybe we can continue this discussion in the chat? :)

Comment: Domi is right; API != JSON endpoint. You're just building an API for these weird robots called humans

Comment: PERFECT comment! love it! If i could up vote your humor I would create multiple accounts for you ;)

Comment: @jackweirdy: Can you clarify that? I am neither interested in JSON endpoints nor APIs. API means application programming interface. I fail to see how an HTML frontend would qualify for that label.

Comment: @Domi: Sorry, but you don't actually know what REST is. It *can* be applied to design APIs, but that is only a tiny slice of what it covers. Please do read the Wikipedia article on the subject. To quote: "Representational State Transfer is intended to evoke an image of how a well-designed Web application behaves: presented with a network of Web pages (a virtual state-machine), the user progresses through an application by selecting links (state transitions), resulting in the next page (representing the next state of the application) being transferred to the user and rendered for their use".

Comment: @bock2dos As you know building a frontend representation for your HTML pages you can place the form wherever you want - the RESTFull API i described above (api.example.com) is the thing you call it. so it's totally okay for the HTML form to be on /questions/ask but the form there should be submitted on /questions with POST (so you are calling REST the right way). Also to mention: I know what REST is but as you see I'm a backend dev who develops the API not the frontend, but I also have enough knowledge about how REST can be done so I think everything in my answer should be right.

Comment: @bock2dos And another questions for you... I don't think you are able to say that i don't actually know what REST is. The up votes on this answer should show you that it's a complete "trustful" answer and i'm not the only one who thinks that this is the right way!

Comment: @back2dos Sure. APIs are used to transfer data between two otherwise-independent systems. In this case, a HTML form facilitates passing information from a browser (which in turn, gets it from a user or their autocompleted common responses) to a web server. The server does something with it, and sends back another wad of data, formatted as HTML. Data goes in, data comes out, it just so happens that the data is in a HTML document.

Comment: @Domi that is called [Argumentum ad Populum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) and is an informal fallacy. You said "i showed you what REST is - and as you can see it is about designing a API not designing a pattern for writing a url for an enduser!" is just wrong. REST is certainly not just about designing APIs and it is very much about how you structure URLs for an enduser. Wikipedia is very clear on that. Please use authoritative sources to back up claims to the contrary.

Comment: @back2dos The REST (i learned while studying) was to design an API and so I lived with this in my mind. I never came to the idea to put REST as a thought into the frontend. I always thought an still think that for the enduser it should be as clear as possible what is happening and why. So for me the frontend can set the path as they want it to be or let's say set the path as "the enduser will have the most advantage". You are right the sentence with "... a pattern for writing a url for an enduser" isn't 100% right, so in this point you are right.

Comment: @back2dos I still think if you are thinking about REST - the first thought will be to define an API for an web app and this app is allowed to have every path it want. It would be totally legal to do something I told this: on www.stackoverflow.com/questions you display the html template with the parsed json you got from api.stackoverflow.com/questions (GET). Next: www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask would represent a form which sends the data to api.stackoverflow.com/questions (POST) and if everything went right you will be redirected: www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/submit .

Comment: @back2dos Note here: stackoverflow does it like I descriped in the first part of the answer. There is a api.stackoverflow.com and a webapp on www.stackoverflow.com - the webapp sends and receives data from api.stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: @Downvoter: please let me know why you thing this isn't a good answer so I can improve it. thanks

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can understand your question, you want an application that :

- displays HTML pages (and eventually other formats ?)
- displays form views for creation of new elements or for update of existing ones
- accept POST/PUT with url encoded data (sent by submitting above forms) to create of update those elements (and eventually other formats ?)

Ruby on Rails is a framework that is targetted as this kind of requirement. Extract from the guide [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.18/routing.html) :

```
HTTP Verb   Path            action      used for
GET        /photos          index       display a list of all photos
GET        /photos/new      new         return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST       /photos          create      create a new photo
GET        /photos/:id      show        display a specific photo
GET        /photos/:id/edit edit        return an HTML form for editing a photo
PUT        /photos/:id      update      update a specific photo
DELETE     /photos/:id      destroy     delete a specific photo
```

You can have HTML views for the actions index, new, show and edit.

Personally, I would recommend to add the following :

```
POST       /photos/:id        update    update a specific photo
POST       /photos/:id/delete destroy   delete a specific photo
```

so that it would be simpler to update or delete elements via html forms.

All those paths are only Rails convention and are not imposed by REST but it gives a clean example of what can be done.

But it is quite easy to make an application following the same or slightly different conventions using other frameworks. Java + Spring MVC can do that very easily, with HTML views using JSP, Velocity, Thymeleaf or others, and the possibility of using JSON in input or output simply using HTTP headers or suffixes in URL (`GET /photos/:id.json`) with a little less magic but more control than RoR. And I'm not an expert in other framework like Struts2 (still Java), or Django (Python) but I am pretty sure that it is possible too.

What is important :

- choose a language (Ruby, Python, Java, PHP, ASP.NET, ...)
- choose a framework compatible with RESTfull urls
- ensure you can have views in HTML, or JSON, or *enter the format you want* by adding a suffix or a HTTP header and eventually the appropriate adapter/converter

You could do it *by hand* but frameworks limits boiler plate code.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I've had trouble with myself, and which I don't think there's a right answer to.

Assuming I have an API exposing `/people/:id`, I generally reserve an endpoint for `/people/new`. a `GET` request to that url with `Accept: text/html` will return a form for creation, but anything else will throw a 404, since this page only exists for people in a web browser. The form on that page will then post to `/people/` as you'd expect.

Similarly, if someone wants to edit an existing person, the form to do that might be served from `/people/1/update`, again HTML only.

If your API has that structure, then I think reserving keywords such as `new` or `update` is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Best answer for me, although I can't say I'm really satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of REst was never about how URLs looks like,but how http verbs and headers are used to transfer datas.

This whole "restfull urls" thing is made up by people who dont understand what Rest is. All the Rest spec says is that URLs must be unique.

Now if you really want "restfull" forms,then form should be a resource with an id, like /form/2929929 .Of course it doesnt make sense to do so,since forms are strictly for web users and REst doesnt care about how data is acquiered, only about how it is transfered.

In short,choose whatever URL you want. Some frameworks use new and update for forms. By the way the /questions/ask/submit is totally valid in a Rest context, because what you submit and a question can be 2 totally difference resources.

Comment: My point exactly: In this case what I submit and a question are the same resource and the URLs do not reflect that. Do you see why one might take issue with that? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that there is a difference between a RESTfull application and a REST client.

A RESTfull application has pure restfull urls as you described, such as

```
GET     /persons   : gets a list of all the persons in database
POST    /persons   : adds a new person
GET     /person/1  : gets a person with id 1
PUT     /person/1  : updates person with id 1
DELETE  /person/1  : deletes person with id 1
```

and so on...

Such an application does not have any forms or UI for submitting data. It only accepts data via HTTP requests. To use such an application you can send and receive data using tools like **curl** or even your browser, which allow you to make HTTP requests.

Now, clearly such an application is not usable from the user point of view. Hence we need to create client applications which consume these restfull applications. These clients are not restfull at all and have urls like:

```
GET     /person/showall  : displays a list of all persons
GET     /person/create   : shows new person form
POST    /person/create   : submits the data to the restfull application via ajax or simillar technology.
```

and so on...

These clients can be another HTML application, an android application, an iOS application, etc.

What you are trying to do here is create a single application which has both restful urls for objects as well as forms/pages for data display and input. **This is absolutely fine.**

Just make sure that you design proper restfull urls for your objects while you can have any url you find suitable for your forms.

Answer (score 0):

In 100% RESTful Web services resources are identified using descriptive URLs, that is URLs composed only of noun phrases.

Generaly speaking, for creating a new resource, you would use `PUT`, although some frameworks (such as Zend Framework 2, if I remember well), use `POST` for this purpose. So, for creating a question you could `PUT questions`, then providing the question identifier in the body of the request, or `PUT questions/{identifier}`, thus providing the id in the URL.

Comment: Again, this question is about under which URL the form should be to actually perform the request from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Contemporary web/cloud applications have moved to what is known as a single page application architecture.

This architecture has a back end REST API (typically JSON based) which is then consumed by either single page applications or native client apps on mobile phones and tablet. The server is then much easier to implement and scale and provides the needed access regardless if its a web client or a native phone/tablet platform.

The client architecture is known as MV*  for Model, View and * is anything else the framework provides such as controller logic and persistence.

In my applications I have used a number of MV*  frameworks and libraries in anger and investigated many many more. I've had some success with backbone, and my favorite Ember.js, although there are many frameworks and everyone has their favorite for different reasons and that is a whole topic on its own. I will say that depending on the needs of your application different frameworks will be more or less appropriate. I know what matters to my productivity so I have settled on Ember after doing the rounds.

On the backend you have a similar myriad of choices but choose a platform that is known to be mature and stable ans same goes for your data persistence.  There are a number of cloud services that give you a REST/JSON api with no coding or deployment concerns now so you can focus more on the client development and less on the server.

It is important to understand that in single page applications the browser url does not need to have a 1 to 1 correspondance with the backend rest api. In fact it would be detrimental to usability taking such a simple minded approach.  Of all the client frameworks Ember gets this right as it has a built-in router, and as a result client state is captured in the URL so the page can survive a refresh and can also be bookmarked. You really can keep your client view independent to the backend api endpoints. I design my client URLs around the menu/structure of my forms. In complex apps the URLs nest as far as I need the app to partition and drill down into the details, yet the api endpoints are flat and may span multiple service providers.  A view in my client app often assembles data from multiple endpoints and similarly on Accept/Save it pushes to multiple endpoints. It is also possible to implement local persistence so the web client can be used offline and so that temporary or half filled out forms can survive a page refresh.

Another consideration with such an architecture is SEO. With single page applications one needs to be able to provide prerendered pages to web crawlers. Fortunately there are a number of tools which can auto generate the pages for single page applications so that web crawlers can still index your sites content, tools such as pretender.io and many others can solve this for you.

At the end of all this you have a server with a number of REST endpoints and typically a single index.html, app.js app.css and any other assets such as images and fonts.

Typically you need a toolchain for generating these files from your source code which are then either hosted on your domain or on a CDN. I also configure my app and server for CORS so the web client can be hosted on a different domain to the REST back end which also works well in development.

I recommend the broccoli or ember-cli tool chain for assembling all your web client assets and I have also had good experience with Brunch.  I've tried most of the tools out there and those are the only ones that get my vote.

For API design I've been actively providing feedback on the latest drafts of JSON API. There is a lot of good work being done there and you can use that as a good starting point.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that this boils down to sidestepping the problem by using client side logic to construct editing UIs (in which case one doesn't really need a single page approach, only enough client logic to construct such a UI on demand on the appropriate pages)?

Comment: You could have a client that can generate its own views dynamically say based on some schema information either embedded in the client app or associated with the resource via some link header or link reference within the resource. However if you are wanting a good user experience like say stack overflow then your client side logic will have intimate knowledge of the back end API and contain its own templates for rending  views and logic for handling UI events and so on.  Have a look at the Ember.js main page (or your framework of choice) for an example of how an app works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in production Web Applications I recommend separating how static content is delivered vs how dynamic content is delivered.

Let us hope you are not constrained by SEO and can actually use the wonder of DOM manipulation (ie Client-Side templating)...

I would highly recommend going down the path of learning how to create a SPA (Single Page Application)

However, back to the topic at hand.

Static content (HTML, CSS, Javascript, images) should be delivered thru a different server than your dynamic content (the REST data in json/xml format).

Your HTML should use JQuery/AngularJS/Backbone -- some type of JavaScript framework to actually "render" your HTML on the client-side using JavaScript.

The JavaScript frameworks will also make the proper RESTful calls to POST or PUT a form (which should be a UI representation of some REST path)

Lets say you have a form for a Profile,

```
GET /profile/{id}  would be called to pre-populate a profile FORM

PUT /profile/{id}  would be called to update the profile
```

** JavaScript will pre-populate the FORM by calling one or more RESTful GET methods.

** JavaScript will take entered data from FORM and POST/PUT it to the RESTful server.

The point you should take away from this is:

Let an advanced JavaScript library handle the sending of RESTful requests and "rendering" of the HTML.

HTML is only a template (static content) and can be hosted on a completely different server that is optimized for the job of delivering "static content" :)

Hope that makes sense.

Cheers!

P.S.
   Learn about Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) if you have not already. You will likely need that knowledge to properly host your static content on a different server/domain than your dynamic content.

Comment: I am just getting started with Rest APIs and I am wondering about an API ressource for forms. I mean the forms are created by the client-side app but what about all the data that the forms consume. Database queries to add options to select, etc.. I'd rather have one single api call to query all the necessary data than make a resource per each relation. Say there is a select with a list of countries and another with a list of categories I don't want to call get /categories then get /countries. I'd rather call a get (resourcename)/form to make all those calls

Comment: I don't want to add those calls to a vanilla get /(resourcename) call and I may want to make the vanila call public and block access to form to unidentified users and return an error message instead...