# spring-data-rest override @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Using **spring-boot** and **spring-data-rest** to create a quick starter web app template.

I want the root `/` to be allowed through to the `src/resources/public/index.html` file so I can have my front end start up but using **spring-data-rest** the `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController` is mapped to `/`.

How can I move its mapping to say `/rest`? I can find how to amend the BaseUrl for the `RestRepositories` but  not how to free up `/` ?

Comment: Why are you trying to run your API directly on the same paths than your front end application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring the base bath is straightforward. Extend RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration (either in your main Application class or in a separate config class) and then override its primary config routine as follows:

```
  @Override
  protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
    try {
        config.setBaseUri(new URI("/rest"));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: that just moves my respostories to have a prefix it does not move the list repository controller mapped to the root /

Comment: @spstorey, it moves the root list method for me (using Spring Boot 1.1.8 which I believe uses spring-data-rest 2.1.4)

Comment: I was using 1.2.0.M2 swapped and now it works fine, thanks and I'll log it with spring.

Comment: Oliver Gierke kindly confirmed issue is version based from the issue I raised, https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-411

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to run your API directly on the same paths than your front end application?

This should be done in 2 separate applications. Spring Data + Rest should be used to create an API and than using your frontend (which may be running on an simple apache elsewhere) to call the RESTful API you created as a Backend Developer.

Here you can find my answer to an RESTFul API:
[Where to put forms / alternative views in a RESTful html app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696982/where-to-put-forms-alternative-views-in-a-restful-html-app/24782518#24782518)

As you can see the API is running on another Server/Part of the server.

Comment: This is meant to be a rapid prototype startup project so I want the front end (angularjs) and the rest api just in one app. I want / to serve index.html and the rest api to be just some other path say /rest/.. or /api/..

Comment: Sorry, but you shouldn't do that! these are 2 completely different technologies you want to combine. A Java Rest API needs to run inside an container like Tomcat or similar, but on the other hand the AngularJS only needs an Apache - this is a lot more overhead than just splitting these two PARTs of your app. Even it is a rapid prototype startup project - it would be failure at the first step of coding...

Comment: Hi Dominik- What wrong in combining them, I started a prototype and doing the exact same thing. Two app client app running a lite-server build in angular2 and backend app in Spring Data Rest and JPA etc. Now the end product of front-end app is wrapped in the WAR and configures a static resource handler in Spring to serve the static resources.

Comment: I understand you should have 2 servers one for client and one for server side but since we have a in-house data-center, it would be very difficult to get approvals to install [say nodeJS]. Is it wrong to do it this way?

Comment: @AVI It's all about maintenance. I've worked with many of those "prototypes". If you would build an WAR file - with the Frontend included you would have to redeploy the whole .war file also if you would simply change some styles. At one point your prototype may be working as you and your marketing people would expect - at this point it will be hard to argument "I will have to separate the frontend from the backend". Why not go with the separate projects directly?

Sure you can setup a build pipeline to still have the code base of frontend and backend separate and only merged after...

Comment: @AVI an release or hotfix. I know it's strongly opinionated but after many projects with different agencies I've made the experience that keeping the backend code (if an API) as much separated from an single page application as possible. You can still use the same server (don't get me wrong). But you can use subdomains - the api.example.org would be on the same machine only pointing to your jboss, jetty or tomcat and the www.example.org would serve the index.html directly (apache, nginx serving).

Comment: @AVI As I said - it's strongly opinionated and but also since 2014 - my experiences in those kind of things just showed mainly the same over and over again. (hope those comments somehow covers your questions?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143921/discussion-between-avi-and-dominikangerer).